# How can I make email that starts with digit to look properly on RTL not test-mail.com@000?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have a problem with emails that have only digits in first part of the email for example `1892813@testdomain.com` in `rtl` direction. Even the app using `rtl` direction in Arabic version of it I would like to stick with `ltr` direction for the emails. The only problem is that with numeric based first part of the email it looks bad inside of input,

The example code

```
<b-input
    class="custom-input"
    dir="rtl"
    type="e-mail"
    :value="value"
    @input="handleInput"
  ></b-input>
```

```
.custom-input {
  [dir="ltr"] & {
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    direction: ltr;
    text-align: left;
  }

  [dir="rtl"] & {
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    direction: ltr;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

So when `rtl` direction is set for entire app I would like to have value inside of input `0000@testmail.com` instead of `test-mail.com@000`

Example sandbox with input https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-leakey-tnd7h?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Hey Verthon: can you clarify what you mean by "Look Good"? Is there an actual technical error or a proper desired outcome you are looking for?

Comment: Please include all relevant code here on Stack Overflow, not just on CodeSandbox.

Comment: Even if there's a link to codesandbox, a screenshot of desired and undesired behavior would be good to have here. Saying "it doesn't look good" without illustration triggered some zealots to close your question, I voted to reopen but please update your question to be more self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

try this on your input

```
    direction: ltr;
    text-align: right;
```